# Backlight brightness on Mint 16 (GeForce 330M)

Tags: laptop, linux-mint, lcd, brightness, backlight

I have Dell Vostro 3700 with GeForce 330M and use the nouveau driver. I have Mint 16 with Cinamon.
I want to be able to change backlight with keyboard shortcuts. I did some changes to kernel parameters, so now I can change brightness from command line, by echoing number to /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness.
In the meantime, I have another directory /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight, but echoing there doesn't change anything

Keyboard shortcuts are also captured. Cinamon shows brightness slider, but using it changes content of dell_backlight/brightness, not nv_backlight.
How can I enable changing brightness (in nv_backlight dir) from desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a workaroud:
Create a script in /usr/bin/update-backlight

```
#! /bin/bash
cp /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
```

And add an udev rules /etc/udev/rules.d/80-backlight.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", ACTION=="change", DEVPATH=="/devices/platform/dell-laptop/backlight/dell_backlight", RUN+="/usr/bin/update-backlight"
```

This copies value one value to another every time I change backlight brightness.